# Lucene QuaryParser

Tags: java, lucene

I want to know what fits precisely in the variable class string QueryParser. 
In the documentation is written this:
 [image]

But I did not understand what you mean!

Answer (score 0):

Considering your document has multiple fields, default field is the field where your query will be searched for.

For example if you have a document like following

```
document{
 author:"Erik Hatcher and Otis Gospodnetić"
 BookTitle:"Lucene In Action"
 Description:"The book covers end to end apis of lucene"
}
```

Now let's say you search for word "Lucene" and your default field is "BookTitle" then that's where your query will be matched and this document will be part of search results. But if you search for word "book" and your default field is "BookTitle" then you will get no results back.

Answer (score 0):

The field name defined there will be the field used when you do not specify a field in the query itself.

You may be more accustomed to explicitly defining the field to search within your query like:

```
content:(relevant terms) title:mytitle
```

In which the default field has no affect at all, but I could enter a query without any explicit fields defined:

```
some terms
```

which would be understood by the queryparser to be searching in the default field, like:

```
defaultfield:some defaultfield:terms
```

Similarly, you can mix the two together, like:

```
title:mytitle other terms
```

which would be interpreted, by the query parser, as:

```
title:mytitle defaultfield:other defaultfield:terms
```

The Lucene [Query Parser Syntax documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Fields) describes the use of the default field.